# How to duplicate/make a copy of a JfreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to make a copy of an existing JFreechart and associate it several times with a mouse click
Here is what I was trying:

```
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) 
{ 
    JFreeChart tempChart = existingChart;
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(tempChart);
    //View Frame
}
```

The same variable is used several times. The problem I encounter is, the previous chart also gets replaced when I make the second mouse click.

Is there a way to create a fresh copy somehow ?

Comment: Did you try `clone()` yet?

Comment: Clone does work. I need to manually enable the pan and zoom functionality though.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, use the standard Object function `clone()` to copy objects in the majority of circumstances.

For the record, all I did was look up the [JFreeChart javadoc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) to check. [Documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html) is your friend.

Comment: Clone requires additional exception handling mechanisms, that's why I thought if there was any easier fix.